# How to perform some action when i click on html submit control without using runat server

Tags: html, asp.net, button, aspx-user-control

I have 2 textboxes and 1 submit button in my asp.net webform. Those controls are purely HTML controls and I don't want to use `runat="server"` property.

Now, when the user clicks the submit button, some action should be performed. For that where I have to write the code, and how to write the code in `*.aspx.cs` page.

And one more issue is, how to maintain the state of my html controls. Please clarify my doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure understand your question, but if you want to keep HTML form be pure HTML, you can use Generic Web handler, add a handler in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="Handler Name" />
  <add name="Handler Name" verb="POST" type="Handler Name" path="/Handlerpath.ashx" />
</handlers>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="/Handlerpath.ashx"><input type="text" name="foo" /> </form>
```

Create a class and use `IHttphandler` interface as it's base class:

```
class myhandler : IHttphandler{}
```

then use `ProcessRequest` method to get form data.

```
        var foo = context.Request.Form["foo"];
```

Comment: Finally i got the solution. Thanks a lot